# Memory leak in ios when fetching data from XML

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

is there any generic[image] approach to fix this kind of memory leaks in ios application.

I am fetching 5000 images from server and saving then in document directory while saving their path in core data.

here is code

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnectionWithTag *)connection
{
    NSNumber* nn66 =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

    if ([nn66 isEqualToNumber:connection.tag])
    {
        NSXMLDocument* rElement  = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[dataFromConnectionsByTag objectForKey:connection.tag] options:0 error:nil];
        NSXMLElement* element    = [rElement rootElement];

        NSArray*  shadowElement3 = [element elementsForName:@"PRODUCT_NAME"];

        for (int i = 0; i <  [shadowElement3 count]; i++)
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                Product* failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product"                                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];

                NSXMLElement* element11 = [shadowElement3 objectAtIndex:i];

                NSString* strPath = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_COD"];

                NSArray *paths                =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory  =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *savedImagePath      =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strPath];

                [array        addObject:savedImagePath];

                if (getimages == NO)
                {
                    //**************************************************
                    NSData* receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[element11 stringValueForNode:@"img"]]];
                    [receivedData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
                    //**************************************************

                    //**************************************************
                    int testNo = ((i+1)*100)/[shadowElement3 count];
                    NSMutableDictionary* dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:lineNo]];
                    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[NSNumber numberWithInt:testNo] intValue]] forKey:@"status"];
                    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self onlyDateFromDate:[NSDate date]]]      forKey:@"syncDate"];
                    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1] intValue],[[NSNumber numberWithInt:[shadowElement3 count]] intValue]] forKey:@"totalloaded"];

                    [tableDataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:lineNo withObject:dic];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"settingdata"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tableDataArray forKey:@"settingdata"];
                    [_mtable reloadData];
                   // [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(ricaelleupdatecompleted:) withObject:dic];

                    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(ricaelleupdatecompleted:) toTarget:self withObject:dic];
                    //**************************************************
                }
                else
                {
                    NSString* newImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_t",strPath];
                    NSString *savedImagePath1      =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:newImagePath];


                    [array        addObject:savedImagePath1];

                    int testNo = ((i+1)*100)/[shadowElement3 count];
                    NSMutableDictionary* dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
                    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@ Completo",[[NSNumber numberWithInt:testNo] intValue],@"%"] forKey:@"status"];
                    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self onlyDateFromDate:[NSDate date]]]      forKey:@"syncDate"];
                    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1] intValue],[[NSNumber numberWithInt:[shadowElement3 count]] intValue]] forKey:@"totalloaded"];
                    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(allimagesCompleted:) toTarget:self withObject:dic];
                }

                failedBankInfo.images = array;
                failedBankInfo.DA1_FILIAL = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_FILIAL"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_CODTAB = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_CODTAB"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_CODPRO = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_CODPRO"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_ITEM   = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_ITEM"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_PRCVEN = @"100"; //[element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_PRCVEN"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_X_PROM = @"10"; //[element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_X_PROM"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_X_ALTE = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_X_ALTE"];
                failedBankInfo.DA1_X_PRFI = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"DA1_X_PRFI"];
                failedBankInfo.B2_FILIAL  = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B2_FILIAL"];
                failedBankInfo.B2_COD     = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B2_COD"];
                failedBankInfo.B2_LOCAL   = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B2_LOCAL"];
                failedBankInfo.B2_QATU    = @"25";// [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B2_QATU"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_FILIAL  = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_FILIAL"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_COD     = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_COD"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_DESC    = strPath;
                failedBankInfo.B1_TIPO    = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_TIPO"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_UM      = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_UM"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_LOCPAD  = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_LOCPAD"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_GRUPO   = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_GRUPO"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_IPI     = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_IPI"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_POSIPI  = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_POSIPI"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_ALTER   = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_ALTER"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_ALT_P = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_ALT_P"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_LAR_P = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_LAR_P"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_COM_P = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_COM_P"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_PESO    = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_PESO"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_PESBRU  = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_PESBRU"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_ALT_C = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_ALT_C"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_LAR_C = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_LAR_C"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_COM_C = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_COM_C"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_DIA_P = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_DIA_P"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_DIA_C = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_DIA_C"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_PLI_C = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_PLI_C"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_PBR_C = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_PBR_C"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_ALT_M = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_ALT_M"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_LAR_M = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_LAR_M"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_COM_M = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_COM_M"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_DIA_M = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_DIA_M"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_PBR_M = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_PBR_M"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_PLI_M = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_PLI_M"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_PGCAT = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_PGCAT"] intValue]];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_CXMAS = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_CXMAS"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_CODBAR  = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_CODBAR"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_DUN14 = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_DUN14"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_TS      = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_TS"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_TE      = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_TE"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_X_DESCR = [element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_X_DESCR"];
                failedBankInfo.B1_QE      =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];     //[[element11 stringValueForNode:@"B1_QE"] intValue]]; //[eleme

                NSError *error;

                if (![context save:&error])
                {
                    NSLog(@"error occured");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"clientes Saved copupons");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    if (getimages == NO)
    {
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait we are processing images"];
        [self performSelector:@selector(complieImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
    }



    NSNumber* nnn =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
    if ([connection.tag isEqualToNumber:nnn])
    {
        [self  saveClientTableData:nnn];
    }

    NSNumber* nn5 =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    if ([nn5 isEqualToNumber:connection.tag])
    {
        [self saveBannerData:nn5];
    }

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [Utils readAllCoreData];
    [dataFromConnectionsByTag removeObjectForKey:connection.tag];
}
```

Comment: what code is causing the leak?

Comment: Where is the problem? If you have allocated a memory then you have to release that. Just give the code. You can also try using ARC if it is not.

Comment: Generic Answer:  Find out where you are allocating a CFString without CFReleasing it

Comment: I am using ARC and it showing crash at following code     [_mtable beginUpdates];
    [_mtable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lineNo inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [_mtable endUpdates];

Comment: When looking at your leaks, I find it's often useful to click "invert call tree" and "hide system libraries". That way, the call tree will show what line of your code allocated the leaked item. It won't show you where it leaked, but at least it will identify which item leaked, which makes it easier to diagnose. I'm assuming you're using ARC (otherwise you have leaks in the above code). Also, don't forget to run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu).